# How to create a bool BST::CloneSubtree(BST t1, type item) function and how to call in main ? I'm very new to BST .Thanks ;)

Tags: c++, data-structures

[3.1 and 3.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtB2S.png)

Function bool BST::CloneSubtree(BST t1, type item) that will clone a subtree in t1 where the root of the subtree contain value item. For example, if t2.CloneSubtree(t1, 126); is called, then the subtree in t1 (t1 is tree in Figure 3.1 and t2 is cloned subtree in Figure 3.1 (a))  where the root contain node 126 will be cloned and store in t2 as shown in Figure 3.1 (a) below. t1 will not change after function call and t2 must be an empty tree before cloning. Display t1 and t2 using preOrderPrint() after function call
Below are the code i wrote myself. But it can't works So what's wrong with it ?

BTNode.h

```
using type = Student;

struct BTNode {

        type    item;
        BTNode  *left, *right;
        BTNode(type);
};
```

BST.cpp

```
    //clone subtree

bool BST::CloneSubtree(BST t1, type item) {
    BTNode* cur = t1.root;
    int key = item.id;
    
    if (cur == NULL)  return false;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        if (key > cur->item.id)
        {
            cur = cur->right;

        }
        else if (key > cur->item.id)
        {
            cur = cur->left;
        }
    }
    //cur->left = t2->root->left;
    CloneSubtree2(root, cur);
    cur->item.print(cout);
    return true;
}

bool BST::CloneSubtree2(BTNode* t2,BTNode *cur) {
    if (cur == NULL)return false;
    type item;
    t2 = new BTNode(item);
    t2->item = cur->item;
    cout << cur->item.id;
    if(cur->left!=NULL)
        cur->left = t2->left;
    if (cur->right != NULL)
        cur->right = t2->right;
    CloneSubtree2(t2->left, cur->left);
    CloneSubtree2(t2->right, cur->right);
    preOrderPrint();

    return true;
}

void BST::preOrderPrint() {
    if (root == NULL) return;// handle special case
    else preOrderPrint2(root);// do normal process
    cout << endl;
}

void BST::preOrderPrint2(BTNode *cur) {
    if (cur == NULL) return;
    cur->item.print(cout);
    preOrderPrint2(cur->left);
    preOrderPrint2(cur->right);
}
```

BST.h

```
struct BST {

        int     count;
        BTNode  *root;

        // print operation for BST (same as BT)                 
        void preOrderPrint2(BTNode *);  // recursive function for preOrderPrint()
        void inOrderPrint2(BTNode *);   // recursive function for inOrderPrint()
        void postOrderPrint2(BTNode *); // recursive function for postOrderPrint()

        // sample operation (extra functions) - same as BT
        void countNode2(BTNode *, int &);       // recursive function for countNode()
        bool fGS2(type, BTNode *);                  // recursive function for findGrandsons(): to find the grandfather
        void fGS3(BTNode *, int);               // recursive function for findGrandsons(): to find the grandsons after the grandfather has been found
        
        // basic functions for BST
        void insert2(BTNode *, BTNode *);       // recursive function for insert() of BST
        void case3(BTNode *);                   // recursive function for remove()
        void case2(BTNode *, BTNode *);     // recursive function for remove()
        bool remove2(BTNode *, BTNode *, type); // recursive function for remove()
        


        // basic functions for BST
        BST();
        bool empty();
        int size();
        bool insert (type);     // insert an item into a BST
        bool remove(type);          // remove an item from a BST
        
        // print operation for BST (same as BT)
        void preOrderPrint();           // print BST node in pre-order manner
        void inOrderPrint();            // print BST node in in-order manner
        void postOrderPrint();          // print BST node in post-order manner
        void topDownLevelTraversal();   // print BST level-by-level

        // sample operation (extra functions) - same as BT
        int countNode();        // count number of tree nodes
        bool findGrandsons(type);   // find the grandsons of an input father item

        bool deepestNodes();  //find the deepest node
        bool Deepest2(BTNode *, int); // recursive function for deepestNodes()

        bool display(int, int);//display student information
        void inOrder( BTNode *, int);// print in ascending order
        void reverseInOrder(BTNode *, int); // print in descending order


        bool CloneSubtree(BST , type );
        bool CloneSubtree2(BTNode*, BTNode *);
        bool copy_bst();
        bool copy_bst(BTNode *n);
        bool *clone(BTNode  *root);

        bool printLevelNodes();
        void printLevelNodes2(BTNode *, int );

        bool printPath();
        bool printPath2(BTNode *, int [], int); //recursion  function for external path
        bool printPath3(int [], int );//recursion  function for external path
        
        
    
};




#endif
```

Comment: "But it can't works So what's wrong with it ?" That's not very specific of what you think it should do, and what it does. We also don't know what the definition of BST is. We need a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to be able to help

Comment: Assigning to a function's (non-reference) argument - for instance, `t2 = new BTNode(item);` - has no effect outside the function. There is nothing special about pointers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.